# isEqualToString always returns NO/false

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a webview in which I want to invoke Obj-C Code, I do it like in [thisTutorial](http://davinccoder.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/call-ios-method-for-html-button-click/comment-page-1/#comment-128)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
  NSString *absoluteUrl = [request.URL absoluteString];
  NSLog(@"STRING: %@",absoluteUrl);//prints out didTap://button1
  NSString *sayHello = @"didTap://button1";
  if ([sayHello isEqualToString: absoluteUrl]) {
      [self sayHello];
      return NO;
  }
return YES;
}
```

however `[self sayHello]` is never being invoked. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Print out your string like this: `NSLog(@"STRING: >>>%@<<<",absoluteUrl);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are trailing spaces or other white characters involved. That would explain the inequality.

Also, you should perhaps use the standard method of `NSURL`:

```
NSString *absoluteURL = [request.URL absoluteString];
```

To remove spaces, do this:

```
absoluteURL = [absoluteURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                           withString:@""];
```

Comment: I used the asboluteString, this was lost while copying Code, sorry about that!! I think I will look for trailing spaces. Hmm, does anyone know how to remove them?

Comment: hmm no luck, I also did a [absoluteUrl length] before and after the replacing, the length is the same. The problem seems to be something else. Maybe the Encoding?

Comment: I just changed the didTap://button1 to fake://button1 and now it works. *shrug*